# How to use INSERT INTO with variables in python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

**What is wrong in the following code syntax**

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUE (%s)' % (table, Column, Value))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works on my version of Python. In my opinion, there is a problem with the string. Update your `cur.execute()` accordingly.

`>> Table = "Kutta"`

`>> Column = "Says"`

`>> Value = "Bhow"`

`>> FINAL_STRING = "INSERT INTO " + Table + " (" + Column + ") VALUE (" + Value + ")"`

`>> FINAL_STRING`

`'INSERT INTO Kutta (Says) VALUE (Bhow)'`

Comment: > Table = "Sheet1"
> Column = "Description"
> Value = "GoodMorning"
> FINAL_STRING = "INSERT INTO " + Table + " (" + Column + ") VALUE (" + Value + ")"
> cur.execute(FINAL_STRING)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'GoodMorning' in 'field list'")

Comment: Your FINAL_STRING should work.